# How do I get specific data from a specific column in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My data is like this:

[image]

I want to take all the data in the column `dokumen_name` which contains A12345.

This is my query:

```
<?php 
        require "init.php";
        $sql = 'SELECT Id, dokumen_name, 
               tanggal, aksi, lokasi
               FROM log WHERE dokumen_name LIKE "A12345"';

        $result=mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

        if(! $result ) {
            die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row["Id"];  ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["dokumen_name"];  ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["tanggal"];  ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["lokasi"];  ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["aksi"];  ?></td>
      </tr>      
      <?php
        }
      ?>
```

It does not show anything. What did I miss?

Comment: This is now how `LIKE` works, see here for reference: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-like-clause.htm. Specifically, you're missing the `%` sign, so `LIKE "%A12345"'` would be better.

Comment: You're question is kind of low quality; for example you did not construct a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. To approach a problem such as this, always try out individual parts; for example execute the query and just `var_dump` the result. This way, you would have seen that it does not return a row, and would be closer to solving your error. Then you can look up the LIKE documentation and go on from there. Saves you a lot of time, and shields you from those nasty downvotes :)

Comment: with all do respect, all answers is correct. i cant accept all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this
`$sql = 'SELECT * FROM log WHERE dokumen_name LIKE "%A12345%"';`

Answer (score 1):

If the `LIKE` statement is provided a simple string, such as `A12345`, then it is equivalent to saying `dokumen_name = 'A12345'`.  To avoid this, you can use wildcards `%` to query fields similar to, but not equal to, your search term.  For instance:

```
$sql = 'SELECT Id, dokumen_name, 
           tanggal, aksi, lokasi
           FROM log WHERE dokumen_name LIKE "%A12345%"';
```

Comment: with all do respect, all answers is correct. i cant accept all

Answer (score 1):

Learn **[like pattern](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)**

Create A sql query As Below. The percent sign and the underscore can also be used in combinations!

```
SELECT Id, dokumen_name,tanggal, aksi, lokasi
FROM log 
WHERE dokumen_name LIKE "%A12345%" ';
```

> Tip: You can also combine any number of conditions using AND or OR
>   operators.

Comment: with all do respect, all answers is correct. i cant accept all

Comment: You can select only one as answer @borneo

Answer (score 1):

Change Your sql query like below:

```
$sql = 'SELECT Id, dokumen_name, 
           tanggal, aksi, lokasi
           FROM log WHERE dokumen_name LIKE "%A12345%"';
```

For Like Condition you need to specify `%` with the string

Comment: with all do respect, all answers is correct. i cant accept all